# while read line not working on mac with makefile

Tags: bash, macos, makefile, readline

I am having to do this and it's still not working (i.e. put everything on a single line):

```
commit:
  cat data/commit-folders.csv | while read line; do git add $line/; git commit $line/ -m 'Autocommit'; git push origin master; done
.PHONY: commit
```

For some reason `$line` is showing up as `ine` and I've tried `$(line)` and still no go. I would like to put this on multiple lines too but haven't figured that out.

```
commit:
  cat data/commit-folders.csv | while read line \ 
    do
      -git add $line
      -git commit $line/ -m 'Autocommit'
      -git push origin master
    done
```

The `-` on `-git` is for Makefile to ignore the errors from the command. I would like to maintain that behavior in this situation if possible.

Basically I am trying to read a CSV file which just has a path per line (a folder like `foo/bar/baz`) and I want to commit `foo/bar/baz/` with the trailing slash.

Comment: Doesn’t it look a typo? You have git add $l when you are using $line?

Answer (score 2):

> For some reason $line is showing up as ine and I've tried $(line)

`$` gets expanded by make first. So `$line` is read as `${l}ine`, and as `${l}` is undefined in makefile, it results in `ine`.

Also `${line}` expands to nothing, as in your case it should be a shell's variable, not make's one.

So the right solution is `$$line`, which first (by make) is expanded to `$line`, and then (by shell) to the right value.

> I would like to put this on multiple lines too but haven't figured that out.

With GNU make you can use [`.ONESHELL:`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html)

```
.ONESHELL:
commit:
    cat data/commit-folders.csv | while read line \ 
    do
        git add $$line
        git commit $$line/ -m 'Autocommit'
        git push origin master
    done
    exit 0
```

> The - on -git is for Makefile to ignore the errors from the command

This is needed when you **don't use** `.ONESHELL`. With `.ONESHELL` it basically works as if you execute a shell script file.